# Application performance is much better if I used attach to process rather than launching directly from VS

Tags: .net, performance, debugging

I have a .NET application that takes large amounts of data from a SQL database (10s of Gb), does a lot of computation over many stages, and then writes the result back to said database.

If I compile the program for Debug, launch the exe from Windows Explorer, and then attach the VS debugger via Debug -> Attach To Process then I get considerably better performance than if I launch it initially from within VS, i.e. the latter takes maybe 10 times longer than the former.

The program works by opening a window and waiting for the user to make a couple of selections and then pressing a 'start' button, so I can attach the debugger before the process is begun, and therefore I would have expected the computations to take the same amount of time in either scenario.

Does anybody know of any reasons for this difference in behaviour?

Comment: This is good information but not really a question :o

Comment: Tyler Nichols I'm pretty sure the question is clear but I'll add an obvious one-line question at the end for you

Comment: There will be a big difference for the Release build since attaching does not disable the jitter optimizer.  Debug, no.  The only real other way that the debugger can slow down a program is by spending too much time scrolling the debugger notifications in the Output window.  Exceptions and Debug/Trace messages typically.  Testing the debug build with such huge datasets is not very sensible btw, it doesn't tell you anything about perf and you'll easily drown in the data.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your response.  Unfortunately the software is as it is, and there's nothing I can do about that - it's not mine to change.  I'll keep going